# How to get list of files in directory smb libcurl?

Tags: c, linux, curl, libcurl, smb

I'm trying to get a list of files in the directory with libcurl from the SMB server. But I have a error:

```
curl -u "DOMAIN\login:password" smb://fs/january/soft
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer

curl -u "DOMAIN\login:password" smb://fs/january/soft/
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

If I try to get the file then everything will be okay:

```
curl -u "DOMAIN\login:password" smb://fs/january/soft/asn1ve.rar > 1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9103k  100 9103k    0     0  4056k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 4055k
```

Comment: How is this connected to `C`?  What about `curl -u "DOMAIN\login:password" -s smb://fs/january/soft --list-only`?

Comment: I need curllib C interface. I think that curl and curllib are similar.
command:curl -u "DOMAIN\login:password" -s smb://fs/january/soft --list-only. Output is empty.
Command:curl -v -u "DOMAIN\login:password" -s smb://fs/january/soft --list-only. Output is:
*   Trying 192.168.132.57...
* Connected to fs (192.168.132.57) port 445 (#0)
* Closing connection 0

Comment: Ah, I see. Just an idea.  Can you first mount the `smb` before doing curl?

Comment: This is good idea!)) Also I can use another library. I would like to do this by curllib.

Comment: Try the same `curl` commands with mounted `smb` (e.g. smbclient, smbmount, mount -t (smbfs,cifs)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not currently supported by libcurl. It is however [mentioned in the TODO](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html#File_listing_support) as something that we'd like to see added one day.